# Edit javascript array without reloading the page

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a literal array that is loaded when the page loads... See below:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var members = [
    {
       name:"Alan Lim",
       id:"54700f06-a199-102c-8976-b1732b7ffc74",
       positions:[
          {
             id:"4cdeb2a2-8897-102d-80ee-95364de284f0"
          }
       ]
    },
    {
       name:"Ben Sinclair",
       id:"ed34b5a4-9b2f-102c-8475-9e610b13400a",
       conflict:"true",
       positions:[
          {
             id:"f00c2128-8895-102d-80ee-95364de284f0"
          },
          {
             id:"f00c68ea-8895-102d-80ee-95364de284f0"
          },
          {
             id:"4cde6824-8897-102d-80ee-95364de284f0"
          },
          {
             id:"4cde9ea2-8897-102d-80ee-95364de284f0"
          }
       ],
       locations:[
          {
             id:"88fb5f94-aaa6-102c-a4fa-1f05bca0eec6"
          },
          {
             id:"930555b0-a251-102c-a245-1559817ce81a"
          }
       ]
    },
    {
       name:"Debbie Wright",
       id:"fa49307a-9cfb-102d-bd08-842c500d506d"
    }
]
</script>
```

Is there anyway to edit the array without reloading the page? For example, I want to add `conflict:"true"` to `Alan Lim`...

E.g:

Change this:

```
    {
       name:"Alan Lim",
       id:"54700f06-a199-102c-8976-b1732b7ffc74",
       positions:[
          {
             id:"4cdeb2a2-8897-102d-80ee-95364de284f0"
          }
       ]
    },
```

To this:

```
    {
       name:"Alan Lim",
       id:"54700f06-a199-102c-8976-b1732b7ffc74",
       conflict:"true",
       positions:[
          {
             id:"4cdeb2a2-8897-102d-80ee-95364de284f0"
          }
       ]
    },
```

Trust that makes sense :) The reason for this is because I use other JavaScript to pull information from this array. When I make a change with the other JavaScript I want to add and subtract to this array to reflect the changes...

Comment: You are allowed to dynamically add properties to an array element.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can loop through to find the member you want (by name it seems given the question) then edit it, like this:

```
for(var i=0; i<members.length; i++) {
  if(members[i].name == "Alan Lim")
    members[i].conflict = "true";
}
```

[You can give it a try here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/GGdj3/), or make it a bit more generic like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/GGdj3/1/):

```
function setProp(name, prop, value) {
  for(var i=0; i<members.length; i++) {
    if(members[i].name == name)
       members[i][prop] = value;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Since your array is numerically indexed, Can you not just do:

```
members[0]['conflict'] = "true";
```